# I get this error whenevever I try using getState() method in my react/redux app. What is the reason for getState() is not a function?

Tags: reactjs, getstate

```
    TypeError: getState is not a function

  32 | 
  33 | export const removeFromCart = (product) => (dispatch, getState) => {
> 34 |      getState() 
  35 |     const cartItems = getState().cart.cartItems.slice().filter(
  36 |         (x) => x._id !== product._id
  37 |         );`enter code here`
View compiled
▶ 29 stack frames wer
```

Answer (score 0):

You need assing getState to a var like this:

```
const state = getState() ;
```